# How to recover original signal after 3D FFT?

Tags: matlab, fft

From the MATLAB example of `fftn`:

```
x = (0:19)';
y = 0:19;
z = reshape(0:19,[1 1 20]);
X = cos(2*pi*0.01*x) + sin(2*pi*0.02*y) + cos(2*pi*0.03*z);
Y=fftn(X);
```

I wish to express the `X` by the below form :

```
X2(x,y,z) = F(n,m,p) *cos(kn *x + km *y + kp *z + a(n,m,p)),
```

Where n,m,z=1,2,3... F(.) is the fourier coefficient,

and k denotes for some constant, and a() is the angle.

By assuming that i do not know the formulation of `X`, but i only have the corresponding matrix data, How can i find F(n,m,p)?
Im trying to express the 3d signal data to the form of `X2` given above.

I thought i can use the results of fftn , `Y` ...

Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO!
It might be helpful if you could add more information about what you want to do and especially what your actual problem/question Is. In general: Try to be more precise as that will make it easier for other people to help you :)

Comment: `X = ifftn(Y)`. Don’t try to implement this yourself, it’ll be slow and a waste of your time!

Comment: @Cris. I was sure I'd missed something, but looks like it's really that easy